# Cross Object Update Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Need a little help with a trigger. It’s my first, so I’m probably missing something straightforward.

Trying to update a field on Account when a field is updated on a related (master-detail) custom object. I don’t think I can use a Cross-Object workflow here because the field update is part of an Approval Process - so I’m going with a trigger.

When `Approval_Stage__c = ‘Approved’` on the custom object I would like corresponding field on Account to read `‘Approved’`. If `Approval_Stage__c` is anything else, the corresponding field on Account should be `‘Not Approved’` (or simply mirror whatever `Approval_Stage__c` is on the custom object- `Pending Approval`, `Rejected`, `Submitted for Approval` etc.)

The code below only works when `Approval_Stage__c == 'Approved'` as per the "if" statement - which is expected. I can't however seem to get anything to work when `Approval_Stage__c` is not equal to "`Approved`".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
trigger DealApprovalStatusUpdate on Deal_Approval__c (after Update) {
    //creates a list of all deal approvals that are updated with the associated accountID
    List<ID> approvedAcctIds = new List<ID>();

    for(Deal_Approval__c dealApproval : Trigger.new){
    if (dealApproval.Approval_Stage__c == 'Approved')
    {
       approvedAcctIds.Add(dealapproval.account__r.id);
       } 
 }

    // duplicate the list above and below to hold all non-approved deals ?

   List <Account> approvedAccts = [Select Name, Deal_Approval_Status__c From Account WHERE ID IN: approvedAcctIds];
    for(integer i =0; i < approvedAccts.size(); i++)
    {
        approvedAccts[i].Deal_Approval_Status__c = 'Approved';
     }

    update approvedAccts;
}
```

Comment: What dotMiko has mentioned, should work but would like to say : if custom object is having master detail relationship with Account- why didn't you use Cross object Workflow field updates. Here I'm not seeing any complex logic which warrants use of Trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clear from the other answers to your question but the reason your code is not working is because `dealapproval.account__r.id` is null. Your SOQL query on Account is not returning any records because of this. You should be doing the following to get the Account Id:

```
approvedAcctIds.Add(dealapproval.Account__c);
```

Related objects are not populated in triggers. For example: `dealApproval.Approval_Stage__c` works but if you reference account fields such as `dealapproval.account__r.id` they will be null or return a NullPointerException.

**Alternative Logic:**

If you know the Id of the Account you want to update then you don't need to do a query. You can use the pattern below to directly update the Account without the need for the SOQL statement.

The code below will keep the `Account.Deal_Approval_Status__c` field insync with the `Deal_Approval__c.Approval_Stage__c`

```
trigger DealApprovalStatusUpdate on Deal_Approval__c (after Update) {

    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

    for (Deal_Approval__c dealApproval : Trigger.new) {
        Account a = new Account(
                        Id = dealApproval.Account__c,
                        Deal_Approval_Status__c = dealApproval.Approval_Stage__c
                        );
         accountsToUpdate.add(a);
    }
    if (accountsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update accountsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Or if you wanted the value on Account to be 'Approved' or 'Not Approved' then you can replace this line:

```
Deal_Approval_Status__c = dealApproval.Approval_Stage__c
```

with this:

```
Deal_Approval_Status__c = 
    dealApproval.Approval_Stage__c == 'Approved' 
    ? 'Approved' : 'Not Approved'
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't thinking you wanted to use Account a = new Account ( ) - for some reason I thought that only applied if you were inserting a 'new' account...... I tried a few variations on the code in my question and did see a null pointer exception, so really appreciate the insight as to why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Process Builder to do this:

Have your Process Builder set on your Child Custom Object. You'll want two different criterias in your Process Builder that fire off your updates.

1) if child object approved = yes, send off record update to account with update to the corresponding status - approved

2)  if child object <> approved, send off a record update to account with update to the corresponding status - not approved

Shouldnt need a trigger!

Answer (score 0):

you can Use [Maps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) to have easily the matching between accountId and the approvalStatus.

so your code could be something like this:

```
trigger DealApprovalStatusUpdate on Deal_Approval__c (after Update) {

    Map<Id,String> approvalStatusByAcctIds = new Map<Id,String>();

    for(Deal_Approval__c dealApproval : Trigger.new){
        approvalStatusByAcctIds.put(dealapproval.account__c,dealApproval.Approval_Stage__c);
    }

    // Update accounts
    List <Account> accounts = [Select Name, Deal_Approval_Status__c From Account WHERE ID IN: approvalStatusByAcctIds.keySet()];
    for(integer i =0; i < accounts.size(); i++)
    {
        accounts[i].Deal_Approval_Status__c = approvalStatusByAcctIds.get(accounts[i].Id);
    }

    update accounts;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use this:

```
    if (dealApproval.Approval_Stage__c == 'Approved')
    {
       dealapproval.Deal_Approval_status__c = 'Approved';
    }
    else
    {
       dealapproval.Deal_Approval_status__c = 'Not Approved';
    }
```

then update all your dealApprovals accordingly

Comment: `Deal_Approval_status__c` is a field on `Account` not `Deal_Approval__c`